# Does `epoll_wait` signify which event was triggered when both EPOLLIN and EPOLLOUT were added?

Tags: linux, epoll

Suppose I am specifying both `EPOLLIN` and `EPOLLOUT` flags when adding descriptors to monitor with `epoll_wait`. From the 'epoll' manpages it is unclear what exactly each of the `epoll_event` structures returned as part of the array carries in its `events` field. Quoting:

> the events member will contain the returned event bit field.

Does it mean that it is impossible to distinguish whether an event was triggered signifying 'can-write' as opposed to 'can-read'? Basically there is an event mask, and I would logically expect returned array to signify exactly *what* event(s) have 'happened' on a file descriptor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expectation is right.  The `events` member will contain the event(s) that have occured for that file descriptor.

Comment: is it possible for `events` to contain both `EPOLLIN` and `EPOLLOUT` mask?

Comment: @compile-fan: Yes.  Consider level-triggering where the file descriptor is already readable and writeable when it is polled.